# Use an iPhone 5 Nano-SIM in an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I dropped my iPhone 5 into a pool and had to downgraded to an iPhone 4S. U wanted to transfer my data from the iPhone 5 Nano-SIM card to the iPhone 4.

Are there any adapters or ways to transfer that data?

Comment: iOS doesn't store any data onto the SIM card by default, are you sure there is anything on the SIM worth transfering?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Nano-SIM to Micro-SIM adaptors on the market that will let you drop your iPhone 5's Nano-SIM card in to your iPhone 4. Not only would this bring along any data you had saved on the Nano-SIM, but you'd get your phone number from the iPhone 5 would presumably be assigned to the iPhone 4 assuming all things were equal and the phones were on the same carrier network. Once in your iPhone 4, you could copy the data off the SIM on the phone's internal storage.

I don't want to link to specific purchase sites for these things since that kind of information. But here's a search query that'll turn up many options: https://www.google.com/q=nano+sim+to+micro+sim+adapter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't thought about sim card storage since pre iphone days.   But yes if you did have anything stored on SIM (which I doubt as your previous phone was also Iphone) You can follow the instructions below to get it of.

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Import SIM Contacts.

Full description at:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4994?viewlocale=en_US

Better solution would be to check I Cloud.   Did you ever sign up.   If you did it is possible that you did set it to backup contacts or even more.

Comment: thanks! I got enough off of my computer backup but did sign up for icloud this time so back ups to there now!  only a few photos lost :)